# Difference between Hibernate first-level caching and @Cachable in terms of effect on data retrieval?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, caching

I have been working on a simple application that interacts with the database. I had an endpoint that retrieves Employee data thanks to this service :

```
  @Cacheable
    public Employee getEmployeeById(int id){
        System.out.println("Get the record with id : " + id);
        return employeeRepository.findById(id).orElse(null);
   }
```

When i first tested the api the response took around **100ms** and then on the second test it only took **5ms** because simply it was cached. Later on i tried to remove `@EnableCaching` & `@Cacheable` annotations but the behavior is still the same just because hibernate is using first-level caching by default. I would like to know the difference between both and in such cases is it recommended to rely on hibernate caching mechanism?

Comment: This is not because of first level caching. First level caching is the entitymanager, which will be closed after the request. If you are using JPA or hibernate and are considering using `@Cacheable`, don't. Instead use 2nd level caching in your JPA provider. `@Cacheable` will lead to headaches, especially if you start using this for the same type (or list of types etc.) and also do modificationsl You will need to take care of evicting all entities in each cache yourself. If you setup 2nd level caching in JPA this will be done for you.